# Qemu Linux(kernel with debugging symbols) and ARM

Tags: linux, kernel, arm, qemu

I'm looking for a Linux ARM kernel, disk image and initrd that is compiled with debugging symbols. I'm looking to debug the kernel using the qemu and gdb. Could you point me to an arm linux image that is compiled with debug symbols that I could just start with qemu and connect gdb to? What would be the easiest way to set this up?

Comment: Are you looking for a download of a system, or instruction on how to compile this yourself.

Comment: @Anthon Im looking for a system that has a debuggable arm kernel that I could just use. Id rather not have to compile the kernel myself.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to upload your own kernel and debug it with debug symbols.

you go to your kernel directory then run the command make menuconfig and under

kernel hacking--->  tick the option compile the kernel with debug info

you can also find it under Compile-time checks and compiler options--->

[*]compile the kernel with debug info

Answer (score 0):

I have explained a very detailed setup that just works at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408041/how-to-debug-the-linux-kernel-with-gdb-and-qemu/33203642#33203642

Basically for the kernel config you want:

```
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL=y
CONFIG_GDB_SCRIPTS=y
```